How to record packet/frames data without a pcap header
I'm trying to capture raw/binary Ethernet traffic from my interface, so I can parse it using C. I don't want to parse any PCAP headers. I would prefer without the preamble and end bytes, but it's okay if it's easier to include.
Unfortunately when I capture using Wireshark it always adds a PCAP header.
Consequently I tried Tcpdump:
sudo tcpdump -w - -U | tee ~/test.raw.
However, I open the file in Wireshark, View, Reload as File Format/Capture and it also added a pcap header (see below).
How can I record the raw frame + packets without any PCAP information?


You need some headers, how else would you know many bytes are in a frame?
Anyway, this is all handled for you. libpcap's pcap_next() fills a pcap_pkthdr struct object whose address you pass to it with the length of the packet, and returns a pointer to the start of the packet data in memory.
So, all you need to do is take that pointer, it's your data. The length of the data is in pcap_pkthdr.len, freshly filled in by pcap_next(). So, what you want is already done for you. Simply follow the beginner tutorial from https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html .

Thank you for replying. You're assuming I'm using libpcap..... I'm not. And how do NIC drivers know how many bytes given the PCAP header doesn't exist in real wire traffic?

you should be using libpcap, is what my answer says. Also, you already are (in tcpdump), you just don't realize. The NIC driver knows because the card includes that info in however it gets data from device to host memory. (usually, these are ring buffers of packet buffer descriptors, and the packet buffer descriptors are what you'd call a header here). Thing is, in a driver, you're not trying to put the bytes from packets one after the other in a file. The packets are separate to begin with in the driver. Think of it like this:

When I speak to you clearly (and assuming your hearing works well), you know where one word starts end ends, and can infer the length of words simply as the thing between the gaps between words. Now, remove all the gaps from my speech (or remove all the spaces from written text), and do the understanding again. That's going to be ambiguous! Worse if what I speak aren't words but I just dictate numbers. You lose all usefulness if you write these down without headers; 102 1003 are simple not the same numbers as 10 21003. So, if you write things to a file, you'll need headers. Like it or not.

And now, I frankly don't care about how your headers look, but seeing that the usual interface to capturing packets on most operating systems is pcap, and pcap comes with its headers, and it comes with its header interpreter library, it would be pretty unnecessarily complex to use any other header format.
